# Static files deleted when deploy new version to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: express, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, static-files

I deploy a node.js application with express to elastic beanstalk and my structure is like this:

```
project
├── app.js
├── client
├── apps
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── models
│   │   ├── controllers    
│   │   └── routers
│   └── app2
├── utils
├── views
├── logs
├── scripts
├── public
├── node_modules
├── .elasticbeanstalk
├── .ebextensions
```

I serve my static files in public directory with:

```
{
  "option_settings": [
    {
      "option_name": "/public",
      "namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles",
      "value": "/public"
    },
  ]
}
```

in aws config files in .ebextensions directory.
but when I want to update code with

```
eb deploy
```

aws replace all "/var/app/current/" with project directory so all static files in server deleted.
Is aws pipelines help me? or any other solution?

thank you for your help.